# Spring Cloud Zipkin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin

when I try to integrate Spring cloud Sleuth and Zipkin in my existing Spring Boot application, I get the below error. I have **spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.7.6** and **Spring cloud version as Edgware.RELEASE**. Requesting to please suggest ...

**Error**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedDataBinder
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.getFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:45)
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(HostInfoEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

** Config **

```
@Configuration
public class ZipkinConfig {
    

    @Bean
    public AlwaysSampler defaultSampler() {
        return new AlwaysSampler();  //zipkin-export = true
    }
}
```

** App **

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZipkinServer
public class SpringBootRest2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootRest2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using incompatible versions. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions#supported-releases